# Django ORM select, concat, extract from data and order by

Tags: django, orm

I'm having trouble performing a simple transformation with the django orm. 
Desired outcome should look like this:

```
2018-08
2018-07
2018-06
...
```

And is created with this sql:

```
select
    distinct
    strftime('%Y',a."Buchung") || "-" ||
    strftime('%m',a."Buchung") as YearMonth
from
    hhdata_transaktion a
order by
    1 desc
```

I need it for a ModelChoiceField as queryset, so I'm bound to the ORM here?

My try

```
from django.db.models.functions import TruncMonth, TruncYear

Transaktion.objects
.annotate(year=TruncYear('Buchung'),
          month=TruncMonth('Buchung'))
.distinct()
.order_by('-year', '-month')
.values('year','month')
```

returns:

```
<QuerySet [{'year': datetime.date(2018, 1, 1), 'month': datetime.date(2018, 8, 1)}, {'year': datetime.date(2018, 1, 1), 'month': datetime.date(2018, 7, 1)}, {'year': datetime.date(2018, 1, 1), 'month': datetime.date(2018, 6, 1)}, {'year': datetime.date(2018, 1, 1), 'month': datetime.date(2018, 5, 1)}, {'year': datetime.date(2018, 1, 1), 'month': datetime.date(2018, 4, 1)}, {'year': datetime.date(2018, 1, 1), 'month': datetime.date(2018, 3, 1)}, {'year': datetime.date(2018, 1, 1), 'month': datetime.date(2018, 2, 1)}, {'year': datetime.date(2018, 1, 1), 'month': datetime.date(2018, 1, 1)}, {'year': datetime.date(2017, 1, 1), 'month': datetime.date(2017, 12, 1)}, {'year': datetime.date(2017, 1, 1), 'month': datetime.date(2017, 11, 1)}, {'year': datetime.date(2017, 1, 1), 'month': datetime.date(2017, 10, 1)}, {'year': datetime.date(2017, 1, 1), 'month': datetime.date(2017, 9, 1)}, {'year': datetime.date(2017, 1, 1), 'month': datetime.date(2017, 8, 1)}]>
```

I have the feeling I'm miles away from the desired result..

Comment: You need `ExtractMonth`, `TruncateMonth` gives you the start of the year/month.

Comment: Furthermore in a `ModelChoiceField, you can pass the `choices` dinamically in the constructor, so we can reduce the amount of "SQL magic" and thus do some post-processing in the `__init__` function.

Comment: Furthermore this does not really look like a `ModelChoiceField`: in such field you need to refer to, well, a model. Here you list only year-months. A year-month can refer to multiplie `Transaktion` objects.

Comment: Thank you for all your hints. With extractyear I'm only missing the concat. I think your right with the ModelChoiceField, the idea would be a radio button which should filter multiple Transaktion objects as you have guessed, its just the ChoiceField? I wasn't sure if the choices could be dynamically assigned with the sql?

Comment: Transaktion.objects.annotate(yearmonth=Concat(ExtractYear('Buchung'),
    ExtractMonth('Buchung'))).distinct().order_by('-yearmonth').values_list("yearmonth") gives me the desired outcome, only the - misses as I get a ValueError cause of the integer.. If you want you can post this as an answer as you guided me to this and gave me more to think :) thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to obtain the year or month, you can use [**`ExtractYear`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/database-functions/#django.db.models.functions.ExtractYear) and [**`ExtractMonth`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/database-functions/#django.db.models.functions.ExtractMonth) respectively. Truncating will give you the *start* of the year or month.

So we can rewrite the query to:

```
from django.db.models.functions import ExtractMonth, ExtractYear

qs = Transaktion.objects.annotate(
    year=ExtractYear('Buchung'),
    month=ExtractMonth('Buchung')
).order_by('-year', '-month').values('year','month').distinct()
```

Although it is possible to do the processing at SQL level, I think it will make work more complex. For example if you concatenate the numbers in SQL, it will probably require some work to get leading zeros for months (less than 10). Furthermore it is likely that the query contains "SQL dialect"-specific features making it less portable.

Therefore I suggest to do the post processing at the Django/Python level. For exampe with:

```
from django.db.models.functions import ExtractMonth, ExtractYear

class MyForm(forms.Form):
    my_choice_field = forms.ChoiceField()

    # ...

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        qs = Transaktion.objects.annotate(
            year=ExtractYear('Buchung'),
            month=ExtractMonth('Buchung')
        ).order_by('-year', '-month').values('year','month').distinct()
        self.fields['my_choice_field'].choices = [
            (row['year']*100+row['month'], '{}-{:02d}'.format(row['year'], row['month'])
            for row in qs
        ]
```

Here we thus generate a list of 2-tuples where the first element is some sort of number we use to identify the choice (I here multiplied the year by 100, such that 201804 is april 2018). The second element of the tuple is the string that determines the format.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a list of strings like `2018-06`, something like that should work:

```
[ '%i-%02i' % (x.Buchung.year, x.Buchung.month) for x in Transaktion.objects.order_by(-Buchung) ]
```